# How to list all permutations of $S_n$ for any given value of $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In writing out a symmetric subgroup $S_n$ with some given $n$-value, how would I go about doing this? For example, allow me to attempt with $n=3$:

$S_3 = \{ (1 3), (2 3), (1 2), (1 2 3), (1 3 2), (2 1 3) \}$

Am I doing this correctly or incorrectly? All I know is that $S_n$ has an order of $n!$. In this case, $S_3$ has an order of $6$, so there are six permutations I must list as above.

What about $S_5$? How can I list its permutations generally? I know it has 120 elements, so obviously I just want to list only some just to exemplify. Do I write (I know, it's an incomplete list)...

$S_5 = \{ (1 5), (2 5), (3 5), (4 5), (1 2 5), (2 3 5), (3 4 5), \ldots \}$

Comment: Just so you know, in your $S_3$, $(132)$ and $(213)$ are the same element. Read the first as "1 goes to 3, 3 goes to 2, 2 goes to 1." The second would be read "2 goes to 1, 1 goes to 3, 3 goes to 2." The element you are missing is the identity element which sends 1 to 1, 2 to 2, and 3 to 3.

Comment: You're forgetting the identity in $S_3$, also $(213)$ is the same as $(123)$.

Comment: That work above was written over a month ago when I did not understand permutations and cycles. See my own answer below instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one-line notation, you have $n$ possibilities for the first entry, $n-1$ for the second, etc.

Go through all possible choices of $n$ consecutive entries ($\Leftrightarrow$ one-line notations) recursively.

One can also produce a listing of $S_n$ from a listing of $S_{n-1}$ (again everything written one-line) as follows: take the listing for $S_{n-1}$, make $n$ copies of it, in the $k$th copy put a $k$ in front of each permutation and replace the original instances of $k$ with instances of $n$ in their place.

Comment: Note: this algorithm is known as [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Listing all disjoint cycles:

- $S_1 = \{e\}$
- $S_2 = \{e,(12)\}$
- $S_3 = \{e,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132\}$

and so on. We also have orders $|S_1| = 1, |S_2| = 2, |S_3| = 6$ and so on, which gives way to $|S_n| = n!$.